# Not a very simple riddle

Tags: riddle, mathematics, pattern

When you are one, I am **two**.
When you are ten, I am **four**.
When you are **hundred**, who am I ?

Edit: Also, when you are **thousand**, I am same as i was before.

Edit_2: I can't **move**. I can't see the end. No matter how **big** you are, i am always **small**.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE. Why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to earn your first badge.

Comment: When we are a **thousand**, you are the same as when we were a **hundred**, you mean?

Comment: @user477343 Yes.

Comment: @Lopolo thanks for confirming. I was going to link the word "before" with "four", with "be**fore**".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that given all the clues,

> You are $6$.
>  Your rule is mapping $n$ to the last digit of $2^n$:
>  $2^1=2$, $2^{10}=1024$.
>  As it is a digit, it is always small!
>  Finally, the last digit of powers of 2 is a cycle of length 4: 2,4,8,6,2,... Since 100 and 1000 both are multiple of 4, $2^{100}$ and $2^{1000}$ have same last digit $6$.

Comment: I read your answer as rot13(fvk snpgbevny). Perhaps you could make it less ambiguous?

Answer (score 3):

Could you be

> **Sixteen** $16$?

It appears that the pattern is,

> $$2^x$$ where $x$ is in binary.

Thus we have

> $$\begin{align}2^1&=1 \\ 2^{10}\implies 2^2&=4\end{align}$$

Therefore,

> $$2^{100} \implies 2^4=16$$

Comment: Perhaps the `who am I?` part uses a "who" because [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com)$[$gur ahzore 'fvkgrra' vapyhqrf "grra" juvpu vf fubeg sbe "grrantre".$]$

Comment: How does this account for the `when I you are a thousand, I am same as i was before`?

Comment: @anonymous2 this answer came *before* the edit. I don't know if the user has noticed...

Comment: Oh, gotcha.  Bother these "2 hours ago" thingames.

Answer (score 2):

Could you be

> **Eight** $8$?

It appears that the pattern is described as the ratio,

> $$10^n:2^{n+1}\tag{$n\geqslant 0$}$$

Thus we have

> $$\begin{align}10^0=1&\implies 2^{0+1}=2^1=2 \\ 10^1=10&\implies 2^{1+1}=2^2=4.\end{align}$$

Therefore,

> $$10^2=100\implies 2^{2+1}=2^3=8$$

`Who am I?`

> $8$? You say `who` in reference to a certain **personfication** of the number $8$; i.e., $7$ **ate** $9$.

---

## Answer after included edit

Could you be

> **Nine** $9$?

It appears that the pattern is as follows:

> If we are a number represented by $a$, then you are $${\small\text{The first digit of this:}} \ (a-3)^2-2.$$

Supporting examples:

> $$\begin{align}1\implies (1-3)^2-2 &= (-2)^2-2 \\ &=4-2 \\ &=2\tag{${\small\text{the first digit is}} \ 2$} \\ \\ 10\implies (10-3)^2-2 &= 7^2-2 \\ &=49-2 \\ &=47\tag{${\small\text{the first digit is}} \ 4$}\end{align}$$

Therefore,

> $$\begin{align} 100\implies (100-3)^2-2 &= 97^2-2 \\ &= 9409-2 \\ &=9407\tag{${\small\text{the first digit is}} \ 9$} \\ \\ 1000\implies (1000-3)^2-2 &= 997^2-2 \\ &=994009-2 \\ &=994007\tag*{$\bigg(\begin{align}&{\small\text{the first digit is}} \ 9\\ &{\small\text{too, like before.}}\end{align}\bigg)$}\end{align}$$

`Who am I?`

> $9$? You say `who` because the "average" person works a **nine**-to-five job; and `who` is a reference to how "nin" is included in the word **nin**e, meaning "[an affectionate name for a **grandmother**](http://www.yourdictionary.com/nin)".

**Title:**

`Not a very simple riddle`

> The title has a capital letter `N` since that is the first letter of **nine**.

**Edit 2:**

`I can't move. I can't see the end. No matter how big you are, I am always small.`

> Unsure about the first two lines, but for the last two lines, you are always the **first digit** no matter how big a number we are; i.e., you are always less than $10$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the answer is

> 16. The context involves two persons, my guess the number system is binary.
>
>  Pattern => 2 to the power of me is him.
>
>  2 to the power of 1 is 2.
>
>  2 to the power of (2 => 10 in binary) is 4.
>
>  2 to the power of (4 -> 100 in binary) is 16.

Comment: Look at [**this answer above**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68151/not-a-very-simple-riddle/68154#68154).